# Is there a way to auto-fill parameters in a Shim?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

From the following code:

```cs
using (ShimsContext.Create())
{
    BogusClass.GetMyFakeIdStringStringStringStringStringString //...
}
```

What I normally do is I go ahead and count the number of fields, so it looks like this:

```cs
using (ShimsContext.Create())
{
    BogusClass.GetMyFakeIdStringStringStringStringStringString = (a,b,c,d,e,f) => { return 1; };
}
```

But the way I proceeded here is very tedious, i.e. count the amount of "String" or go to the original function and count the amount of parameters. What I want here is a way for the IDE to auto-complete the amount of fields I need. I don't care what the names are since I can refactor later but I guess the optimal solution would be to have them be auto-filled with the names present in the original function declaration. Can I do that?

Comment: Visual Studio currently does not provide this function to obtain an automatically completed parameter list when using ShimsContext. But you might consider storing these parameter lists in a separate place (such as a configuration file or a centralized constant class) so that you can copy and paste them when needed.

Comment: That wouldn't solve my problem, because I'd still need to do it manually at least once. Also, storing the parameter list -in this case (a, b, c...) wouldn't help me because every list of parameters is different, so it would be copying once and forgetting. For the purpose of reusing it, I can do it once on demand and copy to other test cases. What I mean here is that I want to be able to autofill that parameter list or, at least, allow me to provide a single discard (_) instead of having to specify the exact list of parameters, which is tedious for functions with many parameters.

Comment: So have you considered using placeholders instead of parameters?

Comment: I don't know how that would work, would you please explain what you mean with placeholders?